# Drools kie Repository is not updated while changing rules in Drools Workbench 6.0.1

Tags: drools

**Having issue in drools kie 6.0.1 while integrating drools workbench with application.**

```
String url = "http://localhost:4040/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7.0/maven2/com/dcproject1/dcproject1/1.0/dcproject1-1.0.jar";

    ReleaseIdImpl releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl("com.dcproject1", "dcproject1","LATEST");

    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

    ks.getResources().newUrlResource(url);

    KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);

    // check every 5 seconds if there is a new version at the URL
    KieScanner kieScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
    kieScanner.start(5000L);
```

When I update my rules on workbench via **Drools-6 Workbench UI**, it will throw **Exception**

13:43:16.853 [Timer-0] INFO  o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added:ZipKieModule[ ReleaseId=com.dcproject1:dcproject1:1.0.1file=E:\Users\kjariwala1.m2\repository\com\dcproject1\dcproject1\1.0.1\dcproject1-1.0.1.jar]
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.updateToVersion(KieContainerImpl.java:161)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.updateKieModule(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:214)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.scanNow(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:204)
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl$ScanTask.run(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:193)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

**Should I Change version in workbench when modifying rules.......**

**However, adding new rule or removing existing rule is working very well.....**

**Thanks in adavance....**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution.
In drools 6.0.1, when you create rules in default package, then it create NullPointerException while modifying that rule from droools workbench.